# C++ Standard library that supports time arithmetic

Tags: c++, datetime, time

I have a lot of strings that are in the form "HH:MM" and I constantly have to do arithmetic on them (for example add 5 minutes, add 24 hours, etc).

I am wondering if there is any built in class in the standard library that can handle such arithmetic instead of having to manually change the string and handle corner cases?

Comment: Seems to me it's easier to convert these strings to ints on input, do any arithmetic you want, and then convert it back to this format for output.

Comment: @Mattenii That's what I am doing now. However, sometimes I need to add say "168" minutes. I need to then find how many hours that is, how many minutes, check if the minutes crossed 59, iterate the hour, add the number of hours, see if it crossed 23, and if it did take it mod 24. It just seems an awful lot just to do a basic task (Which I am guessing is not only my problem) which is why I am asking if there is any native support for it.

Comment: In other words, the times are constantly being changed, not only changed once. So I want a class that handles the time conversions/time differences automatically.

Comment: But if you store just one number for the time, say in minutes, then you can add minutes no problem and hours only need to be multiplied by 60.

Comment: Sounds like you want to convert to a `std::time_t` and perform any manipulation on that, then convert it back into a string in whatever format you like. Take a look at the `<ctime>` standard library.

Comment: My above comment isn't quite right--don't manipulate `time_t` values yourself. Use a `tm` object, add the number of minutes you want, then convert to and from `time_t` to normalize it back into hours and minutes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have `strptime` available, and if you have `<chrono>` and don't want to fool around with the C API, you can use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, portable datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to write helpers to convert to and from `std::chrono::minutes`.

So convert from string to minutes, do whatever computation you need, and then convert back to string:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::chrono::minutes
to_minutes(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream in{s};
    in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    std::chrono::minutes m;
    in >> date::parse("%H:%M", m);
    return m;
}

std::string
to_string(std::chrono::minutes m)
{
    return date::format("%H:%M", m);
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << to_string(to_minutes("5:47") + 2h + 168min) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
10:35
```

This library has been ported to recent versions of VS, gcc and clang.

You can also use this library to work with different precisions quite seamlessly, for example seconds, or even milliseconds, and even mix all the precisions you need together:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds
to_milliseconds(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream in{s};
    in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
    in >> date::parse("%T", ms);
    return ms;
}

std::string
to_string(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
{
    return date::format("%T", ms);
}
```

`// ...`

```
    std::cout << to_string(to_minutes("5:47") + 2h + 168min +
                           122s + 465ms + to_milliseconds("1:23:02.123")) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
12:00:04.588
```

Comment: Should've figured Howard Hinnant would beat me in recommending Howard Hinnant's library...

Answer (score 2):

Using `<ctime>` you can convert your HH:MM string to a `struct tm` as follows:

```
struct tm time_components;
memset(&time_components, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
time_components.tm_year = 2017;
strptime("01:45", "%H:%M", &time_components);
```

This assumes you have `strptime` available. If not, use `sscanf` or something similar to extract your hour and minute components--I'm sure you're doing this already. I'm setting `tm_year` there because otherwise it's zero, which is not a valid year for the conversion to `time_t` later on.

We can easily convert the `tm` struct back into a HH:MM string using `strftime`.

```
char buf[6];
strftime(buf, 6, "%H:%M", &time_components);

printf("time_components before manipulation: %s\n", buf);
```

But how about manipulating it? My first thought was 'just convert to `time_t` and add/subtract however many seconds you want'. But `time_t` isn't guaranteed to be in seconds, so don't do that. Instead, add whatever number of minutes you like to the `tm_min` component of the `tm` struct, then call `mktime` with it, which will correctly handle any values that are outside the normal bounds of hours/minutes/seconds. At that point you have a `time_t`, which we don't want to mess with, so just convert that *back* into a `tm` using `localtime`. `localtime` will mirror the conversion that occurred in `mktime`, so you shouldn't have to worry about time zones and so on. Now you've essentially normalized the `tm` structure, and your overflowing minutes have been converted to hours, and your overflowing hours have been converted to days.

```
time_components.tm_min += 65; // Add 65 minutes. Negative values work as expected too!
time_t temp_time = mktime(&time_components);
struct tm* adjusted_time = localtime(&temp_time);
strftime(buf, 6, "%H:%M", adjusted_time);
printf("adjusted_time: %s\n", buf);
```

That `adjusted_time` pointer seems to point to an internal `tm` struct that will change in any subsequent calls to `mktime` or `gmtime`, FYI.

There's no doubt this is a fairly hellish approach. If all you need to do is handle minute/hour overflow and simple arithmetic, I'd be tempted to roll my own or look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration supports the arithmetic and types you want, but I don't think you can construct from strings.

However you can with [Boost Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/chrono.html). I tend to prefer it for most cases, because if I'm dealing with the problem of hours and minutes, I'll probably end up dealing with dates too in the future.